# aws server dies, status check fails

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

This is the second time it happens to me.

My aws server, simply dies, no notifications, I can't ssh to it, nothing.

Only after I restart it, I can ssh and everything goes back to normal.

I check there faq page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html

and simply nothing there, I look at my logs as I attached below, and still nothing... any ideas?

```
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
```

Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.

Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.

Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.

[    2.576125] EXT4-fs (xvda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    2.579775] EXT4-fs (xvda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    2.644278] EXT4-fs (xvda1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    2.647386] EXT4-fs (xvda1): 2 orphan inodes deleted
[    2.650239] EXT4-fs (xvda1): recovery complete
[    2.657120] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.

done.

Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.

[    2.805807] random: init urandom read with 59 bits of entropy available
 * Starting Mount filesystems on boot[74G[ OK ]

- Starting Populate /dev filesystem[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Populate and link to /run filesystem[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Populate /dev filesystem[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Populate and link to /run filesystem[74G[ OK ]
  [    2.958244] EXT4-fs (xvda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard
- Starting Initialize or finalize resolvconf[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Track if upstart is running in a container[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Signal sysvinit that the rootfs is mounted[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Clean /tmp directory[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Clean /tmp directory[74G[ OK ]

Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init-local' at Tue, 08 Nov 2016 11:59:09 +0000. Up 3.47 seconds.

cloud-init-nonet[3.71]: waiting 10 seconds for network device

- Starting set console keymap[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Bridge udev events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Signal sysvinit that remote filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
- Starting device node and kernel event manager[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping set console keymap[74G[ OK ]
- Starting cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
- Starting log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Uncomplicated firewall[74G[ OK ]
- Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
- Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
- Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Bridge socket events into upstart[74G[ OK ]

cloud-init-nonet[4.92]: static networking is now up

- Starting Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
- Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]

Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init' at Tue, 08 Nov 2016 11:59:11 +0000. Up 5.56 seconds.

ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

ci-info: +--------+------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+

ci-info: | Device |  Up  |    Address    |      Mask     |     Hw-Address    |

ci-info: +--------+------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+

ci-info: |   lo   | True |   127.0.0.1   |   255.0.0.0   |         .         |

ci-info: |  eth0  | True | 172.31.63.219 | 255.255.240.0 | 12:7d:8c:19:f4:ef |

ci-info: +--------+------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+

ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

ci-info: +-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+

ci-info: | Route | Destination |   Gateway   |    Genmask    | Interface | Flags |

ci-info: +-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+

ci-info: |   0   |   0.0.0.0   | 172.31.48.1 |    0.0.0.0    |    eth0   |   UG  |

ci-info: |   1   | 172.31.48.0 |   0.0.0.0   | 255.255.240.0 |    eth0   |   U   |

ci-info: +-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+

- Starting Signal sysvinit that local filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Mount filesystems on boot[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Flush boot log to disk[74G[ OK ]
- Starting flush early job output to logs[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay[74G[ OK ]
- Starting System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping flush early job output to logs[74G[ OK ]
- Starting D-Bus system message bus[74G[ OK ]
- Starting SystemD login management service[74G[ OK ]
- Starting system logging daemon[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping Flush boot log to disk[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Handle applying cloud-config[74G[ OK ]
- Starting Bridge file events into upstart[74G[ OK ]
- Starting early crypto disks...       [80G 
  [74G[ OK ]

Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd

- Starting AppArmor profiles       [80G 
  [74G[ OK ]
- Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
- Starting System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
- Starting ACPI daemon[74G[ OK ]
- Starting save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
- Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
- Starting OpenSSH server[74G[ OK ]
- Starting regular background program processing daemon[74G[ OK ]
- Starting deferred execution scheduler[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping CPU interrupts balancing daemon[74G[ OK ]
- Starting configure virtual network devices[74G[ OK ]
- Starting automatic crash report generation[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
- Stopping log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
- Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices[74G[ OK ]

open-vm-tools: not starting as this is not a VMware VM

landscape-client is not configured, please run landscape-config.

- Restoring resolver state...       [80G 
  [74G[ OK ]

Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at Tue, 08 Nov 2016 11:59:12 +0000. Up 7.17 seconds.

- Stopping System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]

Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Tue, 08 Nov 2016 11:59:13 +0000. Up 7.74 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 finished at Tue, 08 Nov 2016 11:59:13 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 7.85 seconds

Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS ip-172-31-63-219 ttyS0

ip-172-31-63-219 login:

Answer (score 0):

Might be a kernel panic or some kind of flaw in the os. Which os/version are you using? Can you check /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/syslog for entries before the crash?

Comment: just happened again, but I can not access the server to see those logs... any ideas what to do?